# My text writer can't be read by my NFC reader

Tags: android, eclipse, text, nfc, writer

so, i make an NFC project, but when i write a text on a tag, my reader can't read it, is there somethin wrong with my format?

this is the text writer format code:

```
private NdefMessage getNoteAsNdef() {

    byte[] textBytes = mNote.getText().toString().getBytes();


    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/plain".getBytes(),
            new byte[0] , textBytes);
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        textRecord
    });
}
```

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're running into charset encoding issues. Try the following instead to create your NdefRecord:

```
byte[] textBytes = mNote.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/plain".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")), new byte[0], textBytes);
```

To create a text tag you can also use the following:

```
byte[] textBytes = mNote.getText().getBytes();
byte[] textPayload = new byte[textBytes.length + 3];
textPayload[0] = 0x02; // 0x02 = UTF8
textPayload[1] = 'e'; // Language = en
textPayload[2] = 'n';
System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, textPayload, 3, textBytes.length);
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], textPayload);
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, i don't understand? is it my reader? but it can read url and contact without any problem

Comment: what my reader can read is like this

WELL-KNOWN: urn:nfc:wkt:T (Text)
Encoding UTF-8
Language: en


but i don't know how to make it like that

Comment: The 2nd option i just added above should do the trick for you

Comment: I put out https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/ for devs like you, give it a try!