# Text format for NFC writing

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, nfc, writer

how to write a text to an NFC tag with format like this?

```
WELL-KNOWN: urn:nfc:wkt:T (Text)
Encoding: UTF-8
Language:en
```

my reader only can read text with format like this, and i'm using this format, it can't work though:

```
private NdefMessage getNoteAsNdef() {

    byte[] textBytes = mNote.getText().toString().getBytes();


    NdefRecord textRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "text/plain".getBytes(),
            new byte[0] , textBytes);
    return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        textRecord
    });
}
```

Thanks Before

Answer (score 0):

See the second option I added to my answer to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432229/908627